# Replacing special characters using sed within windows cmder....and getting an strange error with url parameter

Tags: regex, sed, cmder

I read on a post that when using sed -i in order to replace values containing special characters in becomes necessary to use '|' instead of '/' which works when replacing simple text words.

Eg: sed -i 's|'$original_value'|'$new_value'|g'

where original_value="comprising_special_char_/" new_value="comprising_new_special_char:

I have tried this with shorter less complex strings and it works fine but I'm getting an error message when I attempt this with the following strings.

```
sed -i 's|'category=2fLShbTEL0cKrSR7J9S2hk&emailRedirect=Y'|'utm_source=marketingcloud&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=p8%202021%20donutshop%20lifestyle&utm_content=primary%20cta&brand=Donut%20Shop&emailRedirect=Y'|gi' *.html
```

Can anyone provide help as to why I get the error shown below when running the above command in windows cmder (which uses gnu)?

''category' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: First of all, `&` in the replacement must be escaped. Second, in Windows, you need double quotation marks.

Comment: Does ``sed -i "s|category=2fLShbTEL0cKrSR7J9S2hk&emailRedirect=Y|utm_source=marketingcloud\&utm_medium=email\&utm_campaign=p8%202021%20donutshop%20lifestyle\&utm_content=primary%20cta\&brand=Donut%20Shop\&emailRedirect=Y|gi" *.html`` work?

Comment: Yes. It worked!! Thank you so much for yourhelp!! I was up late last night trying to get this to work with varying combinations of escaping \& and `\&' which I saw someone else attempting to use but they had nested double quotes within the quotes which was throwing additional error message. Aside from & are there any other special characters that would be escaped this way or are there some that would require different escape approach...like for example the \ character itself....i think it's \\

Comment: In the replacement part, only `&` and ``\`` are special and need escaping with a literal backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

- Double quotation marks around the sed command
- Escape `&` chars in the replacement only.

So you need to use

```sh
sed -i "s|category=2fLShbTEL0cKrSR7J9S2hk&emailRedirect=Y|utm_source=marketingcloud\&utm_medium=email\&utm_campaign=p8%202021%20donutshop%20lifestyle\&utm_content=primary%20cta\&brand=Donut%20Shop\&emailRedirect=Y|gi" *.html
```